# What does "Protected area" in Firefox authentication form mean?

Tags: firefox, http

When i try to login to my ups web interface using digest authentication i get next login form:

[image]

The question is what does the "Protected area" part of the form mean and from whom browser gets this string. I have not found any info about this except not very informative commentary from Firefox's repo:

> %1 is an untrusted string provided by a remote server. It could try to take advantage of sentence structure in order to mislead the user (see bug 244273). %1 should be integrated into the translated sentences as little as possible. %2 is the url of the site being accessed.
>   EnterLoginForRealm3=%2$S is requesting your username and password. The site says: “%1$S”

[repo](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/aaac9a77dd456360551dd764ffba4ca4899dcb56/toolkit/locales/en-US/chrome/global/commonDialogs.properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a string provided by the server. It doesn't mean anything in particular.

The dialog you're seeing is a *HTTP basic authentication* prompt. To create it, the HTTP server you're connecting to should send a `WWW-Authenticate` header. This header is constructed [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Protocol):

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Visible Realm"
```

The *realm* is what you're seeing. What realm means is defined in [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-2.2):

> The "realm" authentication parameter is reserved for use by
> authentication schemes that wish to indicate a scope of protection. [...] The realm value is a string, generally assigned by the
> origin server, that can have additional semantics specific to the
> authentication scheme. [...] The protection space determines the domain over which credentials can
> be automatically applied.  If a prior request has been authorized,
> the user agent MAY reuse the same credentials for all other requests
> within that protection space for a period of time determined by the
> authentication scheme, parameters, and/or user preferences (such as a
> configurable inactivity timeout).

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the htaccess configuration and a custom defined string. Have a look at your config for it.

Answer (score 0):

The text that is display is sent by the server as part of the [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header. It’s called the “realm”.

The following header would result in the prompt you’re seeing:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected area"
```

In Apache httpd, this text can be configured using the [`AuthName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authname) directive.